# Looping a function with irregular index increase

Tags: python, while-loop

I have my function:

```
import numpy as np

def monte_carlo1(N):
    x = np.random.random (size = N)
    y = np.random.random (size = N)

    dist = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    hit = 0
    miss = 0


    for z in dist:
        if z <=1:
            hit += 1
        else:
            miss +=1

    hit_ratio = hit / N

    return hit_ratio
```

What i want to do is run this function 100 times each for 10 different values of N, collecting the data into arrays.

For example, a couple of the data collections could be generated by:

```
data1 = np.array([monte_carlo1(10) for i in range(100)])
data2 = np.array([monte_carlo1(50) for i in range(100)])
data3 = np.array([monte_carlo1(100) for i in range(100)])
```

But it would be better if I could create a while loop which can iterate 10 times to produce 10 arrays of data instead of having 10 variables data1...data10.

However, I want to be able to increase the values of N inside monte_carlo(N) by irregular amounts, so in my loop i cant just add a fixed value to N each iteration.

WOuld someone suggest how I might build a loop like this?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
N_vals = [10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 3000, 5000, 7500, 10000]


def data_mc():
    for n in N_vals:
        data = np.array([monte_carlo1(n) for i in range(10)])
    return data
```

I've set up the function like this but the output of the function is just one array, which suggests im doing something wrong and the N_values isnt being cycled through

Comment: Why not create a list for all your 10 values `n_vals = [10,50,100,...]` then do a loop like this: `for n in n_vals:` in which you pass `n` into the monte_carlo function and append the array result to some list of lists or other data structure to store your lists.

Comment: As suggested above but with dict comprehension: `data = {n: np.array([monte_carlo1(n) for i in range(100)]) for n in (10,50,100,...)}`

Comment: I just made an edit to the post, because I'm only managing to output the array for the first value of n in n_vals @Karl

Comment: @bigdaddy the `n_vals` are being looped through, but you are only returning the last time the `data` list is set. You need to put each data list into another list or dict. Something like `data_lists = []` at the start of your function. Then `data_lists.append(data)` after you set it. Then `return data_lists` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a `pandas.DataFrame` where the row index is the value of `n` for that iteration and the columns represent each of the `repeat` iterations.

```
import pandas as pd

def calc(n_list, repeat):
    # this will be a simply list of lists, no special 'numpy' arrays
    result_list = []

    for n in n_list:
        result_list.append([monte_carlo1(n) for _ in range(repeat)])

    return pd.DataFrame(data=result_list, index=n_list)
```

This would allow you to do some data analysis afterwards:

```
>>> from my_script import calc
>>> n_list = [10, 50, 100, 250, 500]
>>> df = calc(n_list, 10)
>>> df
         0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
10   0.600  0.800  0.700  0.800  0.600  1.000  0.800  0.800  0.700  0.900
50   0.840  0.860  0.700  0.860  0.740  0.860  0.780  0.740  0.740  0.820
100  0.770  0.780  0.730  0.790  0.780  0.730  0.760  0.740  0.770  0.690
250  0.784  0.804  0.792  0.768  0.800  0.780  0.792  0.800  0.804  0.764
500  0.798  0.776  0.782  0.786  0.768  0.798  0.786  0.774  0.774  0.796
```

Now you can calculate statistics per value of `n`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> stats = pd.DataFrame()
>>> stats['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
>>> stats['standard_dev'] = df.std(axis=1)
>>> stats
      mean  standard_dev
10   0.7700      0.125167
50   0.7940      0.061137
100  0.7540      0.030984
250  0.7888      0.014459
500  0.7838      0.010891
```

This data analysis shows you, for example, that your predictions get more accurate (smaller `std`) as you increase `n`.